# Android openGL cryptocurrency miner

Tags: android, bitcoin, opengl

I am a hobbyist bitcoin miner who happens to also enjoy a healthy array of powerful android devices. I recently began mixing the two with android bitcoin mining. Through the weeks of research I've done, I noticed that there are no GPU miners for android. I currently have both a tegra K1 and X1 at my disposal, and am itching to try my hand at GPU mining with them, but I can't find any.

So, are there any GPU/OpenGL miners for android (or Linux4Tegra)?